# Audio Stream Buffering outside package

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

is there a way to use this directly on an actions frame instead of loading from a package?

```
   var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://204.45.27.178:4108/");
        var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(3000, false);

        snd.load(req, context);
        snd.play();
```

this is what I have now, the problem I'v got is that it´s not buffering correctly and the sound stream keeps cutting and resuming so many times its annoying.

```
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.ui.ContextMenu;
import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;

var miStream:Sound = new Sound();
miStream.load(new URLRequest("http://204.45.27.178:4108/"));
var miCanal:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
miCanal = miStream.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK... After wrestling for a couple of hours and reading over an over the flash site I found a way to make it work.

```
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;
import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;

var MyStream:Sound = new Sound();
var miBuffer:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(5000);
MyStream.load(new URLRequest("http://204.45.27.178:3006/"), miBuffer);
var miCanal:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

miCanal = MyStream.play();
```

I'v tested it and its working fine, Hope this helps some one else with the same problem :)